# IDEA kept updating indices

Tags: android, intellij-idea, flutter

[image]

Similar IDE blinking issue found here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2017

I am using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-182.3684.101
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6
Dart Plugin 182.3911.9
Flutter Plugin 27.1.3
```

This only happens AFTER setting up the project with Android (if ignoring Android setup it will be fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196167) fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1 specific to Android plug-in. Please update to the current version.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html

Comment: Update Android plug-in or?

Comment: Android plug-in is bundled, you have to update IntelliJ IDEA from 2018.2 to 2018.2.1.

Comment: From the link I only found links to the release note (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2018.2+182.3911.6+Release+Notes), please paste the direct download link here.

Comment: Does "IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1 (build 182.4129.4), released on Aug 09, 2018" fix this issue?

Comment: > We addressed one of the constant indexing problems in IJ 2018.2.1

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html has 2018.2.1 version with the fix for the indexing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Invalidating Caches solved the problem

**Go to File-> Invalidate Caches/ Restart...**